# I got a Null Pointer Exception at driver.switchto.frame(frame)

Tags: nullpointerexception, switch-statement, frame

FAILED: CampaignTest

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at 
>   com.test.synapse.Synapse4.UIActions.CampaignPage.Campaigns(CampaignPage.java:282)
>     at
>   com.test.Synapse4.Campaings.TC001_BulkSMS.CampaignTest(TC001_BulkSMS.java:30)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)**
>       ===============================================
>       Default test
>       Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

```
=============================================== Code as===========


public void Campaigns() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
Campaigns.click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
Bulksms.click();`enter code here`
log.info("enter the Campaign Name" +Campaign_Name +"Object of Campaign_Name" 
+Campaign_Name.toString());
Campaign_Name.sendKeys("CampaignTest3");
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Select SenderId" +SenderId +"Object of SenderId" 
+SenderId.toString());
SenderId.click();
Select drop = new Select(SenderId);
drop.selectByVisibleText("Babyshop");
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Click to RecipientType" +RecipientType +"Object of RecipientType" 
+RecipientType.toString());
RecipientType.click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
log.info("Upload the File" +SelectFile +"Object of SelectFile" 
+SelectFile.toString());
uploadfile();
Thread.sleep(3000);
log.info("Select the Excel sheet" +SelectSheet +"Object of SelectSheet" 
+SelectSheet.toString());
SelectSheet.click();
Select sel = new Select(SelectSheet);
sel.selectByVisibleText("Sheet1");Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Select the Mobile number" +MobileNo +"Object of MobileNo" 
+MobileNo.toString());
MobileNo.click();
Select drop1 = new Select(MobileNo);
drop1.selectByVisibleText("MOBILENO");
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Enter the Message" +Message +"Object of MobileNo" 
+Message.toString());
Message.sendKeys("Recharge or Pay Bills & 7 Lucky Winners will get 100% 
cashback every hour.");
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Click on Schedule radio button" +Schedule +"Object of Schedule" 
+Schedule.toString());
Schedule.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
log.info("Click on Date selection" +ScheduleDate +"Object of ScheduleDate" 
+ScheduleDate.toString());
ScheduleDate.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
log.info("Select the Date form Calendar" +Date +"Object of Date" 
+Date.toString());
Date.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Select the Hours form Calendar" +Hours +"Object of Date" 
+Hours.toString());
Hours.click();
Select dropdown1 = new Select(Hours);
dropdown1.getOptions().get(17).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Select the Minutes form Calendar" +Minutes +"Object of Minutes" 
+Minutes.toString());
Minutes.click();
Select dropdown2 = new Select(Minutes);
dropdown2.getOptions().get(5).click();//Minutes();
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Checking the AllowDups button" +AllowDups +"Object of AllowDups" 
+AllowDups.toString());
AllowDups.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
log.info("Click to Submit button and Obejct is:" +Save.toString());
Save.click();
Thread.sleep(6000); 
boolean alert;
if(alert=true)
{Assert.assertEquals("Campaign name already existed in db.", "Campaign name 
already existed in db.", getalertmessage());
System.out.println(alertmessage.getText());
}log.info("Swicth to SendCampaign page:" +iframe.toString());
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
Thread.sleep(6000);
log.info("Click to SendCampaign and Obejct is:" +SendCampaign.toString());
SendCampaign.click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Here the code as

Comment: You should include your code

Comment: Hi Hemal, I place the code under the output.